# How to append text (from txt file e.g englishWord.txt) to the end of all lines (from another txt file e.g PolishWord.Txt)?

Tags: c#

How to append text (from txt file e.g englishWord.txt) to the end of all lines (from another txt file e.g PolishWord.Txt) ? 
i have one txt file with many english word and translated polish word in another txt file. I would like the result to be such as it:

englishWord.txt:

```
familiar
involve
ability
expand
```

polishWord.txt:

```
znajomy
angażować
umiejętność
rozszerzać
```

Program make the result.txt like this:

```
familiar - znajomy
involve - angazować
ability - umiejętność
expand - rozszerzac
```

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.
Sorry for my bad English.

This is what i tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string englishWord = File.ReadAllText("c:/temp/english.txt");
            string polishWord = File.ReadAllText("c:/temp/polish.txt");


            foreach (var lineE in englishWord)
            {
                string lineEnglish = lineE;
            }
            foreach (var lineP in polishWord)
            {
                string linePolish = lineP;
            }
            string result = lineEnglish + " - " + linePolish;

            result = File.WriteAllText"c:/temp/result.txt";


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far, and what you're having a problem with?

Comment: How do you know, which polish Word Means the same as the English Word ?

Comment: Poul Bak - I'm from poland and i know english ;)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to first read the line from both files, split those lines by spaces into two arrays, then iterate through those arrays at the same time. I.E.:

```
System.IO.StreamReader english = new System.IO.StreamReader("englishWord.txt");
System.IO.StreamReader polish = new System.IO.StreamReader("polishWord.txt");

String englishLine = english.ReadLine();
String polishLine = polish.ReadLine();
String englishWords[] = englishLine.split(' ');
String polishWords[] = polishLine.split(' ');

for (int i = 0; i < englishWords.Length; i++) {
    /* Output englishWords[i] and polishWords[i] to result.txt here */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer no longer really works based on the change in the style of input, but Xiaoy312's answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var english = new StreamReader("englishWord.txt"))
using (var polish = new StreamReader("polishWord.txt"))
using (var result = new StreamWriter("result.txt"))
{
    while (!english.EndOfStream && !polish.EndOfStream)
    {
        result.Write(english.ReadLine());
        result.Write(" - ");
        result.Write(polish.ReadLine());
        result.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what is expected. Look at the source of OP post. Each word is on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

This produces results exactly like in the specification. However, if you're trying to build something like a dictionary I'd suggest other formats like writing to Excel file or a csv file.

```
        //load files
        var englishFile = File.OpenText("englishWord.txt").ReadToEnd();
        var polishFile = File.OpenText("polishWord.txt").ReadToEnd();

        //convert to string arrays
        var englishArray = englishFile.Split(' ');
        var polishArray = polishFile.Split(' ');

        //build output string
        String outputString = "";
        //take the lenght of the shorter array in case they're not the same length
        int maxLength = Math.Min(englishArray.Length, polishArray.Length);
        for (int i=0; i<maxLength; i++)
        {
            outputString += englishArray[i] + " - " + polishArray[i] + " ";
        }

        //write output to file
        File.WriteAllText("results.txt", outputString);
```

Comment: Note that someone (not the OP) has just edited the text format specification, so this program no longer produces the output per specification; it produces the output per the original OP's specification. However, I'm not sure the OP intended the specification to be like the edited one.

Comment: Thanks for help but this is not what i wanted, the code from Xiaoy312 is what I meant. Your code needs words in order and prints them out one by on. I thinks it's better for .csv files. Can you explain what mean OP ?

Comment: Ok i found what it's mean.(OP)